# Execute perl script in cron job , "system" command return -1

Tags: perl, cron

```
my $systemDateState = system "date";
my $systemXXXXState = system "xxxx";#xxxx is a program
print "$systemDateState\n";
print "$systemXXXXState\n";
```

This perl script prints two zero. It works from the command line. But when executing this script in cron job, it returns one zero and one -1.

-1 means xxxx never executed. I trid to execute xxxx directly in cron job. xxxx executed normal. And perl script system date in cron job works. Why perl script system xxxx in cron job never executed?

Comment: Perl when started in the cron job may have a different current directory than what you expect.  Try using the absolute path to `xxxx`.

Comment: @dan1111 and different PATH environment variable

Comment: @PSIAlt, yes, but I doubt that is the case since just putting `xxxx` in the cron job is working.

Comment: @dan1111 @PSIAIt I have added PATH environment variable in the cron job. The case here is because the lines end. It's `set Path & xxxx` in a.sh and `set Path & perl script.pl` in b.sh. a.sh in the cron job is working, b.sh is not. The difference is a.sh in Unix-format, b.sh in Win-format. I change the format of b.sh, it is working too. -_-||

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case here is because the lines end. It's `set Path & xxxx` in a.sh and `set Path & perl script.pl` in b.sh. a.sh in the cron job is working, b.sh is not. The difference is a.sh in Unix-format, b.sh in Win-format. I change the format of b.sh, it is working too. -_-||

Answer (score 0):

try to edit your cronjob to force the right directory. For Example:

```
cd cronjobs && perl cronjob.pl
```